# Class' instance methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to see what methods are unique to a class instance (class Pathname). I do:

```
Rails.root.class.methods(false)
```

And I get:

```
[:getwd, :pwd, :glob]
```

Then, I call one of the methods:

```
Rails.root.pwd
```

And I get:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `pwd' for #<Pathname:/Users/borjagvo/workstation/npilookup>)
```

Why do I get this error? How can I see the public methods for instances of Pathname only?

Thanks!

Comment: Does `Rails.root.class.instance_methods(false)` do anything for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call class methods on class, like

```
Rails.root.class.pwd

OR

Pathname.pwd
```

For getting all instance methods (no ancestors nor singleton):

```
pry(main)> Rails.root.class.instance_methods(false) # OR Pathname.instance_methods(false)
=> [:write, :join, :+, :/, :as_json, :directory?, :exist?, :readable?,
    :readable_real?, :world_readable?, :writable?, :writable_real?, 
    :world_writable?, :executable?, :executable_real?, :file?, :size? .....]
# Then you can call above methods on instance of a Pathname
 pry(main)> Rails.root.size?
 => 1248
```

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching the methods from the *class* of `Rails.root`, i.e. `Pathname`'s class methods:

```
Rails.root.class        #=> Pathname
Pathname.methods(false) #=> [:glob, :getwd, :pwd
```

To get the instance's methods, use:

```
Rails.root.methods
#=> [:mountpoint?, :root?, :each_filename, :descend, :ascend, :write, ...]
```

Or, to get its singleton methods: (there are none, it's an ordinary `Pathname`)

```
Rails.root.methods(false)
#=> []
```

Note that `Rails.root` is an instance of `Pathname` and already represents your app's working directory:

```
Rails.root
#=> #<Pathname:/Users/borjagvo/workstation/npilookup>
```